# syntax error with case statement in CONTAINS

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, ssms

```
select  Rowid, @counter
from Patients where 
Contains
((case when @ColumnnName = 'firstname' then firstname  --here
            when @ColumnnName = 'middlename' then middlename 
            when @ColumnnName = 'lastname' then lastname 
           end), SUBSTRING(@parameterFromUser, 1, @counter));   --here
```

I am getting syntax error at `case`, `then` and `@parameterFromUser`. What seems to be wrong with syntax? SSMS shows red aqeakly at these words

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can write this as a single `where` with multiple `contains`:

```
select Rowid, @counter
from Patients
where (@ColumnnName = 'firstname' and Contains(firstname, SUBSTRING(@parameterFromUser, 1, @counter)) ) or
      (@ColumnnName = 'middlename' and Contains(middlename, SUBSTRING(@parameterFromUser, 1, @counter)) ) or
      (@ColumnnName = 'lastname' and Contains(lastname, SUBSTRING(@parameterFromUser, 1, @counter)) );
```

As a note:  I'm not sure how this will optimize.

I might suggest a subquery approach:

```
select *
from (select Rowid, @counter
      from Patients
      where Contains((firstname, middlename, lastname ), SUBSTRING(@parameterFromUser, 1, @counter)) 
     )
where @ColumnName = 'firstname' and firstname like '%' + @parameterFromUser + '%' or
      @ColumnName = 'middlename' and middlename like '%' + @parameterFromUser + '%' or
      . . .
```

This isn't an exact match.  It assumes that the `contains()` will greatly reduce the number of rows being searched.  But, it has certain advantages, such as making it easy to search in multiple columns, if that is desired.

Answer (score 1):

It is just wrong syntax. You can not do this like you are doing.

```
CONTAINS ( 
     { 
        column_name | ( column_list ) 
      | * 
      | PROPERTY ( { column_name }, 'property_name' )  
     } 
     , '<contains_search_condition>'
     [ , LANGUAGE language_term ]
   )
```

You are permitted to use one column or (column list).

You can rewrite as:

```
If @ColumnnName = 'firstname'
    Insert into @ResultTable(...Columns...)
    select  Rowid, @counter
    from Patients where 
    Contains(firstname, SUBSTRING(@parameterFromUser, 1, @counter));  
Else IF If @ColumnnName = 'middlename'
    Insert into @ResultTable(...Columns...)
    select  Rowid, @counter
    from Patients where 
    Contains(middlename, SUBSTRING(@parameterFromUser, 1, @counter));
```

Actually you also can not use `SUBSTRING(@parameterFromUser, 1, @counter)`. You should declare separate variables for this.

Comment: Okay, but the case statement is giving a column name only. This statement is inside of a user defined function , my column name is in a variable and I can not use variable inside a where clause directly . So, can I use the variable here for column_name inside of CONTAINS ?

Comment: There are around 10-15 columns here and I am directly inserting into a table .For ex. Insert into table_name select x,y,z /*rest of the query*/

Comment: Any other possible alternative/similar function that might allow me to do this.

Comment: You mean several if statements?

Comment: I have to add them to a table , how do I do it with these if statements?

Comment: Are you inserting  data in table inside your function??

Comment: @Girogi: Yes, i have substituted the Substring thing with variable, but yet to figure out about the case statements :(

Comment: Yes, I am insertign data into a table variable actually.

Comment: Then you are in trouble, you can not insert in functions. Use stored procs instead

Comment: Oh, its working just fine. Its a multiline table valued function.

Comment: Oh, you are inserting in return table :) I thought you were inserting in base tables. Check updates. You have no other way but duplicate Insert statement in each IF statement.

Comment: I was guessing that :( Okay then. I have come way too far with it so cant change things now .Will do it this way. Thank you so much :)